# One Ajax call is working but the last one is not parsing data to data page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two scripts that are parsing data. The message.php works fine but when I am trying to send data to data.php I am facing the error:

> "Notice: Undefined index: userid in D:\xampp\htdocs\metro\data.php on line 11"

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function post(){
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      if(name==''){
        swal('Type Your Message','You Cannot Send An Empty Message','error');
        return false;
      }
      else{
        $.ajax
        ({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'message.php',
                data:
          {
             message:name,
             userid: <?php echo $get; ?>
          },
                 success: function (response)
          {
            alert(user);
}
        });
        return false;
      }
  }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){
      $('#show').load('data.php');
    },1000);

  });


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var k =<?php echo $get; ?>;
  if(k!=''){

  $.ajax
  ({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'data.php',
    data:
    {
       "userid": <?php echo $get; ?>
    },
     success: function (response)
    {
      alert(k);
}
  });
  return false;
}

});
</script>
```

The error is thrown:

> Notice: Undefined index: userid in D:\xampp\htdocs\metro\data.php on line 11

Comment: Your `$('#show').load('data.php');` -> `setInterval(function(){$('#show').load('data.php'); },1000); });` is not sending `userid` value in `post` like your other 2 `$.ajax()` calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @Sean i am sending data to data.php checkout the last script where code is  $.ajax
  ({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'data.php',
    data:
    {
       "userid": <?php echo $get; ?>
    },
     success: function (response)
    {
      alert(k);
}
  });

Answer (score 0):

In your data.php calling ajax code, you should make below changes:

```
data:
   {
      userid: '<?php echo $get; ?>'
   },
```

You missed quotes from variable value and also added quotes when you are defining key. Hope it helps you.

Comment: i also have tried this but it's not working
above in message.php ajax call this works fine but down when i parse data to data.php it isn't working anyhow
userid: <?php echo $get; ?>

Comment: can you check on console -> network -> click on ajax -> select Params -> check if is passing userid value in your ajax request